# App for Office (Office Add-in) Web Page Possibilities

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-web-apps, csom

I am trying to develop a task pane add-in for Word. Everything online says that at a minimum, the add-in requires a web page, javascript file, and a manifest.

Does the web page have to be done in HTML? Could it be done as an aspx page?
I'm trying to figure out a way for the add-in to authenticate with a SharePoint Online site because it will be pulling down information from a SharePoint List on the site.

A lot of the resources I've found online for authentication is for SharePoint on-premises or it's C# CSOM code.

Is there something I'm missing in terms of getting an Office add-in to authenticate with SharePoint Online or a way for javascript and C# to work together to authenticate with CSOM?

Comment: If you're doing a web page, why not do a SharePoint Add-in?  The helper class takes care of the authentication for you.  You can either use ASP, MVC w/ Razor or plain HTML w/ JavaScript (though all three methods can use JavaScript).

Comment: Read this good article by Waldek. This might not give you the answer you are looking for but it's a good read nonetheless. See : http://blog.mastykarz.nl/refactor-office-add-in-web-page-hosted-sharepoint-application-node-js-cors-office-365-api/

Comment: @wjervis The end goal is an add-in for Word that the user can access simply by opening Microsoft Word so doing a SharePoint Add-in isn't possible.

Comment: @Akhoy Thanks, that was a very interesting read. There's a lot of technologies in there I've yet to work with but it's really intriguing how he worked it out

Comment: Waldek has also written about developing single page applications (your requirement) here: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-office-365-single-page-applications-any-platform/ and which I should've linked in the first place. My bad. Hope this helps